# MediaPlayer How to start playing from the fifth second of the video？

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I want to skip the video's title to play，But I don't know how to do it.If you know, please tell me, thank you.

```
MediaPlayer myMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                    myMediaPlayer.setDataSource(this, Uri.parse(uri));
                    holder = surfaceView.getHolder();
                    holder.addCallback(new MyCallBack());
                    myMediaPlayer.prepare();
                    mTimer = new Timer();
                     mTimerTask = new TimerTask() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            if (isChanging == true) {
                                return;
                            }
                            play_bar.setProgress(myMediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
                        }
                    };
                    mTimer.schedule(mTimerTask, 0, 100);
                    totale_time.setText(getTime(myMediaPlayer.getDuration() / 1000));
                    myMediaPlayer.start();
                    play_bar.setMax(myMediaPlayer.getDuration());
                    myMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) {
                            PlayVideoScreen.this.finish();

                        }
                    });
```

Comment: Can you show apart of your code where you play video by using 'MediaPlayer' API?

Comment: Have you look at MediaPlayer documents? I think you need seekTo(). https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#seekTo(long,%20int)

Comment: @initialise You should consider to paste your code by editing your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use `mediyaPlayer.seekTo(milliseconds).`

Answer (score 0):

Use MediaPlayer#seekTo(int msec) to seek to specified position you wanna set

Comment: Hi Ficat, welcome to Stack Overflow. Remember to keep your posts original and avoid duplicates. The same answer has been posted by someone else before you.